# Uploading large files (greater than 50MB) to an FTP server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I'm currently using the Black Raccoon library in my iOS app to upload small files to an FTP server using the following suggested code:

```
- (IBAction) uploadFile :(id)sender {
//----- get the file path for the item we want to upload
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", applicationDocumentsDir, @"file.text"];

//----- read the entire file into memory (small files only)
uploadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filepath];

//----- create our upload object
uploadFile = [[BRRequestUpload alloc] initWithDelegate: self];

//----- for anonymous login just leave the username and password nil 
uploadFile.path = @"/home/user/myfile.txt";     
uploadFile.hostname = @"192.168.1.100";
uploadFile.username = @"yourusername";
uploadFile.password = @"yourpassword";

//----- we start the request
[uploadFile start]; }


- (NSData *) requestDataToSend: (BRRequestUpload *) request {
//----- returns data object or nil when complete
//----- basically, first time we return the pointer to the NSData.
//----- and BR will upload the data.
//----- Second time we return nil which means no more data to send
NSData *temp = uploadData;   // this is a shallow copy of the pointer

uploadData = nil;            // next time around, return nil...

return temp; }
```

What do I need to do to upload large files (greater than 50MB) without needing to write the entire file to be uploaded into memory?

Comment: Take a look at NSInputStream. https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSInputStream/inputStreamWithURL:

Comment: Use [FTPManager](https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager). It fixes several issues with BlackRaccoon. It streams files without needing to load everything into memory at once. It also compiles clean under iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, FTPManager looks promising.